# "Как Ваш дела" vs "Как Ваши дела"

Tags: склонение

If I'm asking "How are you?" to a singular person in a formal way, why to I say "Как Ваши дела" instead of "Как Ваш дела"? Does "Как Ваш дела" mean anything?

Comment: "Как ваш дела" means nothing. "Дела" is plural, "ваш" is in single. Also, "Ваш" quite often is not uppercased.

Answer (score 6):

We use *Ваши* because it is for the plural *дела*. The whole phrase is in the Nominative case, just like, for example, мои друзья (мои друзья здесь), твои книги (твои книги интересные), **Ваши** столы (Ваши столы красивые) etc.

When we ask somebody about how something/someone is, we use the **Nominative**:

> Как ваши друзья? - Хорошо.
>
> Как твой проект? - Плохо. BUT Как *твои* *проекты*? - Плохо.
>
> Как Ваши дела? - Отлично.

"Как Ваш дела" is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

> Does "Как Ваш дела" mean anything?

No, it's a mistake. The pronoun should be in the plural because it refers to the plural noun дела. **Ваши** is a polite form and it can be used addressing one person and a group as well. If you know a person well you can say

> Как твои дела?

There are also informal greetings avoiding the addressee (we don't say possessive pronouns as often as they are used in English)

> Как дела? Как жизнь? Как оно ничего?(joking) Что новенького?